# ERROR_MORE_DATA ---- Reading from Registry

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I am trying to create an offline registry in memory using the offreg.dll provided in the windows ddk 7 package.

You can find out more information on the offreg.dll here: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210756%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Currently, while attempting to read a value from an open registry hive / key I receive the following error: 234 or ERROR_MORE_DATA

**Here is the .h code that contains ORGetValue:**

```
DWORD
ORAPI
ORGetValue (
    __in ORHKEY     Handle,
    __in_opt PCWSTR lpSubKey,
    __in_opt PCWSTR lpValue,
    __out_opt PDWORD pdwType,
    __out_bcount_opt(*pcbData) PVOID pvData,
    __inout_opt PDWORD pcbData
    );
```

**Here is the code that I am using to pull the data**

```
[DllImport("offreg.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "ORGetValue", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern uint ORGetValue(IntPtr Handle, string lpSubKey, string lpValue, out uint pdwType, out string pvData, out uint pcbData);

        IntPtr myHive;            
        IntPtr myKey;
        string myValue;
        uint pdwtype;
        uint pcbdata;    

uint ret3 = ORGetValue(myKey, "", "DefaultUserName", out pdwtype, out myValue, out pcbdata);
```

The goal is to be able to read myValue as a string.

I am not sure if I need to use marshaling... or a second call with an adjusted buffer.. Or really how to adjust the buffer in C#. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute on the pcbData argument is wrong, it is ref, not out.  You need to initialize it to the Capacity of the StringBuilder you pass for the pvData argument.  Right now the API function probably sees a 0 so will return the error code.

It ought to look something like this:

```
[DllImport("offreg.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint ORGetValue(IntPtr Handle, string lpSubKey, string lpValue, out int pdwType, StringBuilder pvData, ref int pcbData);

  int pdwtype;
  var buffer = new StringBuilder(256);
  int pcbdata = buffer.Capacity;
  uint ret3 = ORGetValue(myKey, "", "DefaultUserName", out pdwtype, buffer, ref pcbdata);
  string myValue = buffer.ToString();
```

Comment: Not really sure what that would look like in code, using my above example could you by chance show me a demo? 

Thank you.

Comment: Btw, the buffer.Append("DefaultUserName"); is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

For out string parameters you should use `StringBuilder` not string.

The general rule is if the parameter is an `LPCTSTR` (`LPCSTR`, `LPCWSTR`) then use string, if the parameter is `LPTSTR` (`LPSTR`, `LPWSTR`) then use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: What if the parameter is PVOID like in my example above?

Comment: @user314749: I think you'll also want a StringBuilder in this case.  It depends on what type of value you're getting though.  You'd maybe have multiple different DllImports for each type of data.

Comment: I know that when pulling values from the registry, there is no defined value type... it could either be string or integer etc. I believe that's why its defined as PVOID... 

So... I attemped to use stringbuilder:

out StringBuilder pvData,
StringBuilder myValue = new StringBuilder("", 256);

However I am still getting the ERROR_MORE_DATA.

Comment: PCBDATA returns 28 when I run the above code... so 256 should be a large enough buffer.